# Core Data, Many-to-many and unique constraint

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

guys!

I have two entities in data model Contact and Group. Contact and Group have many-to-many relations. I've created them as it's described on apple core data manual.

I watched on sqlite file with viewer and it looks good with third table, but there is one problem. Contacts  are not Unique, when I want just to add contact with another group it's being added into Contact table again and into relations table too.

What is the fastest way to make my contacts unique here?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to iOS 9, core data does not have built-in uniqueness constraints. In code before iOS 9, You will have to check if a Contact object already exists in your code with `-countForFetchRequest:error:` before inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

Unique constraints are supported since iOS9 but aren't very well documented. I think all you need to do is add the columns across which you want the constraint in the constraints list in the UI and make sure you have the merge policy you want configured on the managed object context.

This information on the [Ray Wenderlich forums](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=24016&p=98468#p98122) may help and there is a sample project linked.